# Cannot consume all pending transactions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, pending-transactions, txpool

I am trying monitoring pending transactions using my local node. I mentioned that my app **does not consume all pending transactions**.
I compared transaction from my app with etherscan.com or dextools.io. Most amount of transactions were not consumed by my app.
I am using web3js lib with subscription on pending transactions. Also, I have geth as local node.

*So, do I have some issues with my local node or it is expected behavior?*

I tried to increase  **txpool.globalslots** parameter but it did not help me. I still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It's to be expected that a single node can't retrieve all pending transactions, [Blocknative suggests a miss rate of 1%](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/8-lesson-master-the-mempool):

> In our analysis, a single node's mempool in a single geography will
> miss ~1% of all transactions during normal operating conditions. Under
> heavy transaction volumes, the percentage of missed transactions can
> vary greatly.