# [SOLVED]: CANNOT find my pending transactions using: ether.js & [provider.on("pending") and provider.getTransaction(tx)]

Tags: web3js, tokens, javascript, nodejs, ethereumjs

I am using Quicknode and ether.js to monitor pending transactions using the following code:

```
provider.on("pending", async (tx) => {
  provider.getTransaction(tx).then(function (transaction) {

    if (transaction != null && transaction['data'].includes(myAddress)) {
      console.log(transaction['data']);
      console.log(transaction['hash']);
      console.log(transaction);
    }

   })})
```

I have also used transaction.from instead of checking the whole transaction data.

I can find plenty of pending transactions if I don't include myAddress. However, I seem to miss every single of my own pending transactions. I have read [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/95018/cannot-consume-all-pending-transactions) that sometimes not all pending transactions are retrieved. In this case, I have tried retrieving my pending transaction half a dozen times and have never found it.
Why can't I see my pending transactions??

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this thread in the future
Apart from current maintenance this is the reason according to Quicknode customer support:

> First, no provider is capable of seeing the ENTIRE mempool at all
> times. It's a p2p network and the mempool is not consistent across all
> endpoints at all times. There are even private mempools and peers that
> do not broadcast transactions on the network. [...] Also, we do not
> send transactions to the same node that you're listening to
> transactions on, which goes back to the whole not every node will see
> every possible pending transaction problem.

Comment: Hi, where did you find that info?
Also, were you using Polygon testnet?